# Does anyone know what piece this is and its number? Large red hemisphere with angry face

Tags: part-identification

I would like to know what piece this is, found it in my collection.

[image: Large red hemisphere with angry face]

Answer (score 17):

These are [Windscreen 6 x 6 x 3 Canopy Half Sphere with Dual 2 Fingers with Globlin with Yellow Eyes Angry print](https://rebrickable.com/parts/50747pr0013/windscreen-6-x-6-x-3-canopy-half-sphere-with-dual-2-fingers-with-globlin-with-yellow-eyes-angry-print/) and [Windscreen 6 x 6 x 3 Canopy Half Sphere with Dual 2 Fingers with Globlin with Yellow Eyes print](https://rebrickable.com/parts/50747pr0012/windscreen-6-x-6-x-3-canopy-half-sphere-with-dual-2-fingers-with-globlin-with-yellow-eyes-print/). Both come from the same set - [Beast Master's Chaos Chariot (70314)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/70314-1/beast-masters-chaos-chariot/?inventory=1#parts)

Part numbers to all sorts of catalogs can be found on Rebrickable pages linked above.

[image: 70314]